# Bluetooth 4.0 multiple UUIDs?

Tags: bluetooth-lowenergy, uuid

So we are working with Bluetooth 4.0 right now and are orientating the capabilities.

We are developing apps for iOS and Android.

Now while developing for iOS we descovered the service class uuid[b]s[/b]

This presumes we should be able to have multiple UUID's.

The question is:

Is het possible to have multiple UUID's broadcasting in the advertisement package? And how does such a package look like?

Answer (score 2):

It is possible but the available space is limited.

If you are writing firmware for a device you'll probably want to look at some fairly low level documentation.  The Core Bluetooth v4.1 spec, downloadable here https://www.bluetooth.org/en-us/specification/adopted-specifications, describes the format of the advertising packet in Vol.3, Part C, Section 11.  You'll also need the supplement to understand the various data formats.

Answer (score 1):

Yeah it's possible.
is it a RFCOmm or BLE communitcation?

Comment: It's a BLE communication device. We are writing our firmware right now, and we managed to broadcast one UUID, but we want to broadcast 2 UUID's and fetch it with the CoreBluetooth iOS library. But we can't find any documentation about what the broadcast should look like. Do you have information for us?

Comment: You looking for GATT-Specification, you can find some documentation here : https://developer.bluetooth.org/gatt/Pages/GATT-Specification-Documents.aspx or https://developer.android.com/reference/android/bluetooth/BluetoothGatt.html or https://developer.android.com/guide/topics/connectivity/bluetooth-le.html